# Python pyodbc Duplicate key was ignored

Tags: python, sql, request, pyodbc

I am using `pyodbc` and requests module to pull data using web api and push it to my database- `SQL server`.
I making a requests and make a loop over the response inserting it into my database.
in my table column costc is the unique value
Everything works fine, problem is that sometime i may try to insert  costc again and then i get the following error:
pyodbc.IntegrityError: ('23000', '[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Duplicate key was ignored. (3604) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Here's my code:

```
conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Containers(costc,container,descritpion)

VALUES(?,?,?)''',(costc,container,description))

conn.commit()
```

I tried running the following code to avoid duplicates:

```
conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('''IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Containers WHERE costc = VALUES(?))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Containers(costc,container,descritpion) 
VALUES(?,?,?)
END''',(costc,costc,container,description))
```

but I got the following error:
`pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'`

Any idea how to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Just use `WHERE costc = ?` instead of `WHERE costc = VALUES(?)`

Comment: Thanks! so simple, this is indeed was my problem